# KMeans Algorithm Silhouette Score not working. I get the error :

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, k-means, silhouette

I run this code, and my RFM_scaleddf has float values for recency, frequency and monetary values.

```
K_clusters = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
silhouette_scores = []

for K in K_clusters:
    initialised_clusters = KMeans(n_clusters = K, max_iter = 30, random_state = 10)
    initialised_clusters.fit(RFM_scaleddf)
    cluster_labels = initialised_clusters.labels_
    score = silhouette_score(RFM_scaleddf, cluster_labels, random_state = 10)
    silhouette_scores.append(score)
```

The difference is that with RFM dataset, because it has float values, the sklearn silhouette score is not working.

```
K_clusters = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
silhouette_scores = []

for K in K_clusters:
    initialised_clusters = KMeans(n_clusters = K, max_iter = 30, random_state = 10)
    initialised_clusters.fit(RFM_scaleddf)
    cluster_labels = initialised_clusters.labels_
    score = silhouette_score(RFM_scaleddf, cluster_labels, random_state = 10)
    silhouette_scores.append(score)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In [127], line 8
          6 initialised_clusters.fit(RFM_scaleddf)
          7 cluster_labels = initialised_clusters.labels_
    ----> 8 score = silhouette_score(RFM_scaleddf, cluster_labels, random_state = 10)
          9 silhouette_scores.append(score)
    
    TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Comment: `silhouette_score` is not defined, so how can anyone answer the question.

Comment: This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The [mre] should include **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If you don't include a mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.

Comment: feels like `silhoette_score` is a functioned defined somewhere outside this question. And, yeah, it's worth looking at as it's trying to call floats.

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError` informing us that `numpy.float64` is not callable suggests that `silhouette_score` is re-defined from an imported function into a float elsewhere in the code.

i.e.: Check the code for something like this:

```py
silhouette_score = silhouette_score(X, labels)
```

This (`scikit-learn>=1.2.0`) minimal reproducible example should produce no error:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([[-0.686,-0.690,-0.434,-0.418,-0.546,-0.506,0.458,0.454,0.610,0.598,0.410,0.922,0.966,0.878,0.778,0.874,-0.914,-0.962,-0.790,-0.790,-0.842,-0.906], [0.415,0.579,0.635,0.495,0.511,0.323,0.399,0.507,0.459,0.263,0.275,-0.937,-0.893,-0.769,-0.861,-0.933,-0.977,-0.857,-0.941,-0.829,-0.869,-0.781]]).T

km = KMeans(n_clusters=4, n_init='auto', random_state=42)
km.fit(X)
labels = km.labels_

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=labels)
ax.set_title(f"silhouette_score = {silhouette_score(X, labels):.3f}")
plt.show()
```

[image: Simple example showing a 2D scatter plot with four clusters of yellow, blue, violet, and green points in the four corners. The title of the figure reads silhouette_score = 0.853.]

But adding these lines at the end:

```py
silhouette_score = silhouette_score(X, labels)
silhouette_score = silhouette_score(X, labels)
```

Raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hayesall/answer.py", line 15, in <module>
    silhouette_score = silhouette_score(X, labels)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```